# What types of input can i send via web to a web-Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a Web service written in c# sitting on **a.com**

I'm on **b.com**

What are the **input types**  in **a.com** that can be accepted ?

(datatable ,my custom class ?)

p.s. the client on **b.com** is a **web.page** ( **asp.net**)

Comment: In theory: absolutely anything. The backend language has no influence on what a webservice can or cannot accept.

Comment: you can send whatever you want... sometimes this easier to implement, sometimes is is a bit more work to implement... the question is far too general to be answered!

Comment: @Yahia , why is it too general ? ive just asked if i can send anything ? or what is the acceptable types... and if you say - everything - so fine - that's also an answer.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. It just needs to be serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object which is Serializeable can be passed as input and returned from web service. Please follow the following link which list the available return types from webservice and a how-to guide to return a custom class http://www.dalepreston.com/Blog/2005/02/returning-custom-classes-from-web.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know which types you can use for your Contract / Webservice Interface?

Probably everything that can be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Types to be transferred to the web service need to be serializable. Simple types such as int, string and types composed of simple types are usually no problems. Latter if they are known on both sides ( especially when you are using own types ). My experience with web services is a few days back, but I think this hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can be broken to a serialized string. A JSON object is nicely readable/parsable as is XML, but even a primitive byte stream can get pushed back and forth as long as both sides of the fence are aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can send everything you want... as long as both sides share "common knowledge" of what goes over the wire... depending on what specifically you send there might be several options to implement it - varying in scalability, robustness, speed etc.